# Hexo for magazine site

Tags: node.js, hexo

I would like to develop a magazine site using Hexo, I plan to have interviews for my posts.

I chose to use .html and not .md as I wanted my _posts to be styled (titles floating left and images right and so on...) now each post has a lot of html, which means when I want to redo the site design I would need to redo all of the 200+ _post pages?!

Anyone know a good work around?

Thanks Emma.

Comment: have you looked into hexo's templates? https://hexo.io/docs/templates.html

Comment: yes I have, I am using the post.ejs for my articles.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to do a website redesign , all you will need to do is to make a hexo template or find one and you can still use markdown , even posts which are written in markdown are styled when the site is generated so there is no need to use html but you can if you have a reason to do so .